# Call wordpress plugin methods from functions file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm looking to utilize the woocommerce paypal pro plugin in some rest API calls, in my theme's functions.php file. The goal would be to get the constructed html form in one call, and process payment with another.

I still have not quite wrapped my head around how to interact with the plugins classes. Is there a simple explanation or an example of this sort of pattern (for any similar plugin setup) that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm a bit more awake...

It's as simple as interacting with the plugin methods as normal PHP class:

```
$ppp = new WC_PP_PRO_Gateway();
$html = $ppp->payment_fields();
```